# Android application killed because of many image

Tags: android, android-memory

I develop android fragment with a GridList has many image items. When the start to this fragment, the pause screen and start slowly. Also, When start to this fragment multiple times(about 3 times), app was killed.

Code :

```
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_tiro_com_arco), "Archery"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_ginastica_artistica), "Artistic Gymnastics"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_atletismo), "Athletics"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_badminton), "Badminton"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_basquetebol), "Basketball"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_volei_de_praia), "Beach Volleyball"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_ciclismo_bmx), "BMX Cycling"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_boxe), "Boxing"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_canoagem_slalom), "Canoe / Kayak Slalom"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_canoagem_velocidade), "Canoe / Kayak Sprint"));
mGridArray.add(new GridViewItem(getBitmap(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_pictogram_olympic_saltos_ornamentais), "Diving"));
```

(There are many lines in the same manner as above.)

**Anyway, What can I try for this phenomenon? Have you a document or code for I refer?**

I'm a beginner of Android. So my question may seem ridiculously easy. But if you give me the answer I really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: How large are the images? Android does not allow Apps to use a huge amount of the Heap. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: The best reference how to handly bitmap actions is inside tha API: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Use below libs to show image:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: try to show image thumbnails in grid view instead of direct images

Comment: Does your app just crash, or do you get "applicaiton not responding"(ANR)?

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt My app just crash with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Then I'd say try vishals answer below. How many bitmaps are you trying to load anyway? Maybe you should put some kind of buffer somewhere (only load images as they enter the screen), or use smaller images, depending on what you're aiming for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading Google's guides [to 'Load Large Bitmaps Efficiently'](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and then [to load bitmaps with AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html), this should help you out. In fact, read all 5 topics in that guide. Scale the images and load only thumbnails in your `GridView`. :)

Comment: @Stella Wow, that was some fast implementation. :) Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Use these two line of code in  tag in manifest file 
but is support after honeycomb (3.0)

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:largeHeap="true"
```